# Java Email working on spring application locally, but not on deployed Heroku app

Tags: java, spring, email, heroku

So I'm trying to send an email from a deployed spring application on heroku. The emails get sent perfectly fine when running locally, but on heroku I'm getting this error:

javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318141+00:00 app[web.1]: nested exception is:
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318145+00:00 app[web.1]: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318644+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1907)
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318767+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:666)
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318886+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)
2021-04-30T14:46:49.318972+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
2021-04-30T14:46:49.319037+00:00 app[web.1]: at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)

However, this error just magically appeared. It was working totally fine on heroku until yesterday. My guess is maybe heroku just flagged it cause it thought it was suspicious. Anyone know any fixes?

The following is my code:

```
public static void sendEmail(User user) throws MessagingException {    
        //System.out.println("Preparing to send email");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        
        properties.put("mail.smtp.auth",  "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.host",  "smtp.gmail.com");
        properties.put("mail.smtp.port",  "587");
        
        String myAccountEmail = "-redacted-";
        String password = "-redacted-";
        
        User recipient = user;
        
        javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(myAccountEmail, password);
            }
        });
        
        Message message = prepareMessage(session, myAccountEmail, recipient);
        
        Transport.send(message);
        //System.out.println("Message sent successfully");
    }
```

Comment: check that necessary ports are open

Comment: I don't know how to do that @JAsgarov, also it runs locally

Comment: I would be extremely surprised if Heroku permitted outgoing SMTP by default.

Comment: Your comment "also it runs locally" tells me that you dont know what exactly ports are... Please have a quick read, since you need this information https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_(computer_networking) and afterwards google how to open heroku ports

Comment: We had this same thing happen for a JDBC connector to a MySQL database.  Still don't know why.  I don't think opening ports is a promising suggestion.  Our app was able to connect via TLS to MySQL up until a deploy today that contained some minor updates unrelated to the JDBC connection.

Comment: Hi, @owolman, having the same problem with heroku on past days, the application has not been changed in this regard, I'm suspecting something with the container image heroku is using for java dynos. Still investigating, tho

Comment: It turns out was SSL versions on java 11 heroku image. Upgraded the runtime image to java 13 (no problem in my case and it was it). Posting as solution to give visibility, not sure if valid :)

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's a proper solution or if it suits your case, but I've spent the last few days working on this very same issue and the solution was to upgrade the java version heroku runs my app.

In **system.properties** file on your application's root folder:

```
java.runtime.version=13
```

Turns out the java 11 image they are using has some old SSL versions going on and (as far as I am concerned) theres is no way, we as developers, to disable it.

It solved my problem and I hope it solve yours. Not sure it is something Heroku is going to fix in the future for java 11 dynos.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly.

Comment: Worked for me too!

Answer (score 1):

Okay, to fix this enable `TLSv1.2` in your mail properties like so:

```
properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
properties.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
```

Comment: You literally saved my ass tonight, this hint works perfectly,  just to share the glory,  here is my config get java send gmail working:   props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
  props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
  props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
  props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.protocols", "TLSv1.2");